# What are these seals?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I am trying to identify a Chinese watercolor of the Great Wall of China and would like to know what the three seals on the painting mean. The piece is 222” wide and 43” high. Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (*Meta comment*: We need to discuss whether or not image transcription questions are on topic; I brought it up on meta [here](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1937/8099).)

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Does the OP show any interest in learning the content/context of the art piece, or simply requesting the "word recognition and translation" service?

Comment: @r13 I see your point, but we really need to have a proper conversation on the meta site, rather than in the comments of some random question.

Comment: I love the piece I recently obtained and am genuinely interested in trying to learn about it. I do not speak or read Chinese. I have tried every avenue I can to research its history, but to no avail. I thought this was a forum for helping people. Okay f you have another suggestion for me, I am happy to pursue that route. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the second seal is read as “萬事如意” (rant:read from top to bottom, left to right )

the third one is: “金殿彩畫雕刻有限公司” (read from top to bottom, right to left)

Comment: Add the first seal; 春長好

Comment: @dROOOze, omg, i fixated on seal script lah  overall, a product “recycle” verses, topics without any art value 

Comment: OP is also asking what the "symbols" mean?

Comment: 做人做到底, 送佛送到西 :)

Comment: Are the seals identifying the artist or title of the painting?